# undefined reference to slCreateEngine

Tags: visual-studio, android-ndk

Хочу воспроизвести звук через opensl. Подключил библиотеку в Linker->Input->Library Dependencies - OpenSLES. Но линковщик все равно выдает ошибку - undefined reference to slCreateEngine.